NEO4J DESKTOP: "There is no procedure with the name `apoc.custom.declareFunction`..."
Thanks in advance.
As the question says, I cannot use this package in Neo4J desktop version.
APOC FULL is intalled, but in the list of available procedures it seems that there is no "custom" module, as seen in the picture.
Image
This is so frustrating.
NEO4J desktop = 1.5.9
APOC = 5.12.0
OS = Windows
I have installed APOC FULL, restarted and nothing works.
I want to be able to use APOC.CUSTOM procedures.

Starting with version 5, there is no longer an apoc-...-all plugin that contains both core and extended APOC.
For version 5.12, you have to install apoc-5.12.0-extended.jar.
